# how to run a selenium webdriver script using .bat file?

Tags: java, selenium, batch-file

I have scripted a program in selenium web driver using java in eclipse and jre compiler.

now I need to run this code using .bat file.

Could you please guide, how to proceed with it? so that the selenium web driver program can be run using this bat file.

Comment: convert your program to run using either Maven or Ant. and then call this goals using BAT file. I would suggest to go with Maven. Google it and you will find some sample project.

Answer (score 0):

set projectLocation=F:\Selenium\TestNGBatchExample

cd %projectLocation%

set classpath=%projectLocation%\bin;%projectLocation%\lib*

java org.testng.TestNG %projectLocation%\testng.xml